# Ajax Request not working after production build of gatsby js

Tags: javascript, ajax, gatsby

I have a simple form setup on my static gatsbyJS site (using formspree.io). Now I implemented a simple AJAX request instead of redirecting the user to another page.

While in development mode it all works perfectly fine. Once I build and serve the site though, it somehow falls back to redirecting after submitting the form. I just can't figure out whats wrong here, any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my form:

```
<form id='myform' action="http://formspree.io/testmail@gmail.com" method="POST">
  <div className="formgroup">
    <input id='name' type="text" name="name" placeholder='Name'/>
    <input id='email' type="email" name="email" placeholder='Email'/>
  </div>
  <div className="formfield">
    <textarea id='message' name="message" rows='6' placeholder='Message'/>
  </div>
  <div className="formfield">
    <input id='send-button' type="submit" value="Send"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

and here is my Javascript:

```
if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

var contactForm = document.querySelector('#myform'),
   inputName = contactForm.querySelector('[name="name"]'),
   inputEmail = contactForm.querySelector('[name="email"]'),
   inputMessage = contactForm.querySelector('[name="message"]'),
   sendButton = contactForm.querySelector('#send-button');

   sendButton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
     event.preventDefault(); // prevent the form to do the post.

     sendButton.value = 'Sending..';

     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('POST', '//formspree.io/testmail@gmail.com', true);
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

     xhr.onloadend = function (res) {
       if (res.target.status === 200){
         sendButton.value = 'Message sent! I will be in touch soon.';
         contactForm.reset();
       } else {
         sendButton.value = 'Error!';
       }
     }

     xhr.send("name=" + inputName.value + "email=" + inputEmail.value + "message=" + inputMessage.value);
   });
});

}
```

Comment: The definition of Vanilla JS has changed a lot since this legacy code was written. Also, why in the world are you checking if `window` is `undefined`?

Comment: Oh ok will edit accordingly thanks ;) If I don't check for it, gatsby build won't work so I followed the instructions here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/

Comment: Look into the `fetch` function. It will take everything you posted and reduce it to 3 lines of simple code.

Comment: Awesome thanks will definitely check it out. Never used it so lets see.. Would it be too much to ask for a sample piece of code of how you'd do it? Either way, thanks :)

Comment: `var res = await fetch(url, {method: 'POST', headers: {"Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", body: "you get the idea"}}); var data = await res.json();`

Answer (score 2):

After being pointed into the right direction I got it to work..

I used the snippet from https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/1613019/formspree-with-fetch/ and modified it slightly to change the button text while submitting. It works perfectly on a build environment of a gatsbyjs site:

```
if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {

window.onload=function(){
  const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-button')

  const formDataToJson = formData => {
    const entries = formData.entries();
    const dataObj = Array.from(entries).reduce( (data, [key, value]) => {
      data[key] = value;
      if (key === 'email') {
        data._replyTo = value;
      }
      return data;
    }, {});
    return JSON.stringify(dataObj);
  };

  const postToFormspree = formData => fetch(`https://formspree.io/youremail@gmail.com`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formDataToJson(formData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(r => r.json());

  document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    sendButton.value = 'Sending..';

    const formData = new FormData(this);

    postToFormspree(formData).then(response => {
        sendButton.value = 'Message sent!';
        myform.reset();

    });
  });

}
}
```